# Git reset behavior

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I have the following situation:

The **master** branch had a stable version of application.

Developer A recently made a feature-branch called **branch-a** with several commits (let them be **a-1**, **a-2**, **a-3**). Implemented features here are based on up-to-date code from **master** and are well-tested for the moment.

Developer B had a feature-branch called **branch-b** with several commits (for example, **b-1**, **b-2**, **b-3**). For some reason Mr. B had an outdated version (based on master's state of a week or two ago) in his feature-branch and didn't tested the code at all.

Both developers merged their feature-branches to master using:

1. git checkout master
2. git pull origin master
3. git merge branch-X (where X = a,b)
4. git push origin master

No rebase command was used. First this sequence was done by B, next - by A.

When I (developer C) pulled from master, I have seen in **git log** something like:

- a-merge: merge with master by developer A
- a-3
- a-2
- a-1
- b-3 (yes, this commit comes right after one that merges)
- b-merge-conflicts: merge with master by developer B (thousands of files conflicting)
- b-2
- b-1
- master-stable: previous stable commits

As a result Mr. B **somehow** had forced the old version of the code to overwrite the stable version when merging (resulted in b-merge-conflicts commit).

NOW I want to rewrite the history and save **b-1** + **b-3** + **a-1** + **a-2** + **a-3** changes and undo **b-2**, **b-merge-conflicts** and **a-merge**.

My idea is to undo several top commits till **b-1** and then to use cherry-pick patching to apply **b-3**,  **a-1**, **a-2**, **a-3** commits to the new master.

BUT when I try:

**git reset --hard HEAD~7**
I can see a history containing only old commits (before master-stable) without those of branch-a and branch-b.

When I try:

**git reset --hard HEAD~2**

I can see in the history only master-stable commit at the top but NOT **a-2** as I want.

Looks like git reset doesn't translate a digit after HEAD as a number of commits to reset (as I had undestood from the documentation), but as a number of HEAD-changes by git pull (in my examples there are 2).

How can I properly undo the first 7 commits b-2 .. a-merge and rewrite a history starting from b-1?

## UPDATE asked in comments

I used (without --all to exclude additional info)

**git log --oneline --decorate --graph**

```
*   ef7d93f Merge with master by Developer A
|\
| * 2b9dd31 b-4
| * 924a452 b-3
| * 1f9489d b-2
| *   e3cd7a6 Merge by Developer B [2]: Merge branch 'master' from https://github.com ....
| |\
| * | aece506 Merge by Developer B [1]: merge branch
| * | 487e7ee b-1
* | | d9404f8 a-1
| |/
|/|
* | 9b202ce master-stable last commit
```

Comment: Regarding the ordering, try it again with --topo-order. log's usual order is date order, and if you're on windows the clocks on the various machines are probably fairly far out of sync.

Comment: Instead of simply running `git log`, try running `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all`. That would give you a better idea of the state of the repo.

Comment: @jthill well.. Do you mean that it is only order based problem? But then how to explain the behavior of git reset --hard HEAD~2 ?

Comment: Because there are merges involved, a linear display of the commits is not really adequate.  You should first use a tool like gitk or TortoiseGit to show a nice graph of the commits, and let us know how it looks.

Comment: the b-branch commits aren't in HEAD's first-parent ancestry, so without the lgdo @Jubobs suggested your commit-relative resets are working on very bad data.  The first few of the desired sha are safer and usually easier to come up with anyway.

Comment: thanks guys. Need some short brake to build a graph to show

Comment: Use @Jubobs's command. Make an alias for it. It's a decent candidate for the single most useful display in all of git.

Comment: >5min  mine's `git config --global alias.lgdo '!git log --graph --decorate --oneline "${@---all}"'`so --all is just the default

Comment: just updated a question with a screenshot

Comment: The screenshot's works well enough here, copy in the windows terminal is <kbd>alt-space</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd>, drag-select, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  Text is  easier for everybody.

Comment: @jthill totally agree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git log` is lying to you.  It's presenting Git history as if it's linear, it's showing you the commits in date order.  That isn't very useful.  `git log --graph --decorate` will give you a clearer story by showing you the tree (graph really) of commits.  From what I can work out, your repository looks like this.

```
                                       a1 - a2 - a3
                                      /            \
origin c1 - c2 - c3 - c4 - b-merge - b3 -------- a-merge [master]
        \                  /
         b1 -------------b2
```

As you can see, "go back seven commits" can have several interpretations.  This is why you should avoid that notation for moving more than a few commits back, and instead refer to commit IDs.

What you want is this.

```
                  a1 - a2 - a3 [branch-a]
                 /
c1 - c2 - c3 - c4 [master]
                 \
                  b1 - b3 [branch-b]
```

To get there, create A and B branches off c4 so you have a place to build off of.

```
git branch branch-a c4
git branch branch-b c4

             [branch-b]         a1 - a2 - a3
             [branch-a]        /            \
c1 - c2 - c3 - c4 - b-merge - b3 -------- a-merge [master]
  \                  /
   b1 -------------b2
```

Now checkout those branches and cherry pick the appropriate changes onto them, fixing any conflicts.

```
                  b1b - b3b [branch B]
                 / 
                |   a1a - a2a - a3a [branch A]
                |  /  
                | /                a1 - a2 - a3
                |/               /            \
c1 - c2 - c3 - c4 - b-merge - b3 -------- a-merge [master]
  \                  /
   b1 -------------b2
```

That might look like a mess, but now checkout master and `git reset --hard c4` and all the mess kept alive by master being at a-merge will drop away (that's a white lie, origin/master will keep it visible until you push, also Git won't actually throw the commits out for weeks).

```
                  b1b - b3b [branch B]
                / 
               |  a1a - a2a - a3a [branch A]
               |/
c1 - c2 - c3 - c4 [master]
```

Now you can merge A and B normally.  When you're done, you'll have to `push --force` because master is not a child of origin/master.

This is just one way to accomplish what you want.  The important thing is to be able to visualize the repository graph, where you want it to be, and what commands will transform it.

Comment: soooooo, everything looks clear for now. But is there a way to undo top commits presented in linear way (date-ordered)? Maybe with **rebase -i** removing repo-braking commits, reordering in the proper way and fixing conflicts?

Comment: @AndreyPesoshin Thinking about Git commits in terms of date ordering is just another way of pretending its history is linear, and that's only going to get you into trouble.  If you want linear history, you have to make it linear.  Make one branch off c4 and cherry pick b1, b3, a1, a2 and a3 onto it.  But branch history should be preserved, not linearized, in order to retain the understanding that the commits are related (ie. that b1 goes with b3, but a1, a2 and a3 are a separate group).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about `HEAD~` because I usually use `HEAD^`.

You don't need to use that notation though.  You can just supply the hex SHA-1 hash of the commit, or the first 7 or so digits of it.

```
git reset --hard 72abfd4
```

Comment: `HEAD~` and `HEAD^` are equivalent.

Comment: it really doesn't work, 'cause when I checkout to **b-1** (72abfd4 for example), I see the history based on branch-b that looks like broken

Comment: @Jubobs that's because HEAD~ always follows the first parent chain, and HEAD^ just defaults to it. HEAD~7 and HEAD^7 are not equivalent.

Comment: @jthill Sure. I'm only referring to, `HEAD~` and `HEAD^`, specifically.

Comment: do HEAD~3 and HEAD^^^ notations really differ?

Comment: No, ^^^ is three applications of ^'s default follow-first-parent.  ^3 is an explicit follow-third-parent.

Comment: Andrey, try resetting to master-stable's hash then, and cherry pick all the commits from your developers.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I just tried and it really could be a solution.But there came 2 extra problems.

First - cherry-picking of all the work needed is a pain (unlike merge it can't be done automatically in some even simple cases);

Second - I still really want to find a way to just undo some top commits showed in history by standard git log in this situation after 2 huge merges.